# Requesting a JavaScript property in Python (GAE)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, iphone

I'm currently making an iphone web app based on Google App Engine (python). I need to check if the user is browsing not through safari but by the home screen. I can check this with an read-only 'window.navigator.standalone' Boolean JavaScript property as read on: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

How can I read this Boolean in Python? I guess by self.request.headers.get() or something but it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page on HTTP headers and MobileSafari](http://kosmaczewski.net/2009/10/30/http-headers-web-apps-and-mobile-safari/), you can tell if the user has launched your site from their home screen by testing to see whether the string `Safari` is found in the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header.  If it's missing, they are browsing from the home screen.

This seems awfully fragile (and doesn't appear to be documented outside of a couple of non-Apple blog posts), so it might not be the best thing to rely on.